# jQuery Mobile unable to scroll in Spring MVC/ Roo page

Tags: jquery-mobile, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I created a sample web app using Spring Roo and embedded jQuery Mobile 1.1 sample code into a empty jspx page. Below i pasted in the code i used.

This does display just fine.

The problem is that I am unable to scroll up or down.

Does anybody have an idea of what could be preventing the ability of the page to be scrolled or down?

```
<div>
<div data-role="page" id="mylist" data-cache="never">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Persons</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content">   
        <h2>News</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
            <li>Test code.</li>
        </ul>   
        <div class="clear" style="height:20px;"></div>          
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Comment: Why would you down vote this question?

Comment: How did you include the javascript files for jQuery mobile?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I had not thought about that. I got the declaration of my js implemented properly and it now works. I do not yet know the exact cause of the problem but I did have multiple js calls which must have been conflicted. I removed all but the base jquery  and jquery mobile js calls and it now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am updating this so the question can be flagged as answered.  Thanks to bhagyas .

As I commented in the original question to bhagyas I was able to fix this problem by eliminating conflicting js files.